# How to integrate SQL Server 2005 Express in my window application before i built setup wizard

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-2005

How to keep or integrate SQL Server 2005 Express edition (.exe) file in my Windows forms before I built setup wizard? So that SQL Server 2005 Express edition have to install in the client system silently when client installs my Windows forms exe in his system (SQL Server 2005 Express is to access my `.mdf` file which had been placed in my window application) help me out from this issue !!!

Comment: Why don't you just use SQL Server LocalDB?

Answer (score 1):

You do not. This is one of the ideas people get because tehy never think of edge cases.

Problem is - what about updates?

Standard approach is that your installer checks and optionally executes the MSI for SQL Server 2005 express. You do not break installer best practices.

Now, in a setup project - ah - no way? As in - that is a bad technology and thus abandoned anyway. In WIX or any other installer worth a dime (and WIX is as official from MS as it gets) this is done by the EXE that you start for your installing that then checks and installs prerequisites.

Comment: Then what shall i do ?? i need sql server 2005 express to be installed in client system so that he can access .mdf file. Is their any alternative for this @TomTom

Comment: YOu start learning the trechn9ologies you use. Installing prerequisite installers is something that is standard for 20 years, well documented and you have observed quite often. Just learn how other programs do it and copy. and setup project is a crappy technology - use WIX.